# Display main menu vertically (Drupal. 7.9)

Tags: theming, routes

I am not sure how this has happened. but wherever I render the block of my main menu, it displays it's links horizontally rather vertically. Essentially I want to create a main menu that displays its links vertically.

Anybody have a lead on how this can be done ? I am tempted to go into the CSS and alter the theme myself but given that Drupal probably has a switch that allows me to alter the way a main-menu is listed, I want to caution myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and find the style rule that is being applied to the `<li>`elements that will be displaying them inline. Firebug will tell you where the CSS is being loaded and this will lead you to the culprit. One tip is to make sure you're not aggregating CSS so you can find the correct stylesheet. If it isn't theme specific it may be CSS being loaded by a module, but I am confident that there is some CSS there that is creating the result you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like a css issue my friend. Have you changed anything recently in your css that may be cascading into your menu? It is likely that your block elements have been set to inline or floating.

Comment: probably, because I do think I tampered with the CSS at times, alternately, do you advocate creating your own menus or using a menu module ?

Comment: But here's the thing, use any theme I want, it still displays the menu horizontally, so I am assuming that it is not a theme-specific problem, any leads on this ?